# Symfony2, form choice , list of choices depending of mapped entity property

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Let's admin I have an entity   `RestaurantOrder` with a property `status`

`status` can take these values

- `new`
- `accepted`
- `being prepared`
- `delivered`
- `cancelled by customer`
- `cancelled by kitchen`

etc.

Now what I want is that in the backend when I edit one Restaurant order, that the list of `status` presented to me  is dependent of the current `status`

the simplest I've found would for my entity to have a method  `getPossibleStatusChange`  which return an array of the possible choices (using the complex rules given by the business requirements)

But I haven't found in Symfony2 for [Choices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) an option to say "call method from current entity"

I know already how to populate a choices from a **static** callback or from a callback that call the `Repository`

Is there such an option?

Comment: Afaik, there is not. You can access the entity itself from within the form though.

$builder->getForm()->getData() will hand you the entity, where you can access its methods.

Comment: From my understanding of your problem, I think you can change the available status in a prefix treatment while building the form itself to implement the business rules (i.e. 'filterPossibleStatus(order_status)' on the form's order status possible choices while building it). You can add to this a javascript suffix treatment on the page containing the form to check whether the displayed choices follow your business rules.(don't forget to transmit your entity while rendering the twig so the JS)

Comment: @DerStoffel  , thanks actually I think it may solve my problem, let me try.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker, thanks , however I would like to keep javascript as a last resort solution , as it's more difficult to integrate that in our functionnal testing using phpunit.

Comment: Javascript is just a suffix measure. The PHP prefix treatment I described is the most important of my comment. Good luck !

Comment: @DerStoffel  you method work like a charm, can you make into an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: @Answers_Seeker , ok i see now what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a possibility for that.

You can access the unterlying object in the formType though:

```
$builder->getForm()->getData();
```

You can work on that to use your method, to generate your choices.

Comment: yes that's actually enough, after you simply add a method "getNextPossibleStatus(): array"  in your entity (based on the $this->status) ,  to populate the choice, and you're done :)  , thanks.